# Landsat 7/8 RSS Feed for Sentinel 2 A/B

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, sentinel-2

Looking for an image feed like that of Landsat 7 and 8. Anyone know of one?
Examples below: 
https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat/rss/Landsat7_C1.rss

https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat/rss/Landsat8_C1.rss

btw, I am using these feeds to tweet out images that meet a set criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the possibility to use [OpenSearch queries](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/twiki/do/view/SciHubUserGuide/5APIsAndBatchScripting#Open_Search) on Copernicus scihub API

E.g: https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/search?start=0&rows=100&q=platformname:Sentinel-2%20

B̶u̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶n̶o̶ ̶q̶u̶i̶c̶k̶l̶o̶o̶k̶ ̶i̶m̶a̶g̶e̶s̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶S̶e̶n̶t̶i̶n̶e̶l̶-̶2̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶L̶a̶n̶d̶s̶a̶t̶

edit: There are quicklooks, see Kerstens comment below

Comment: There are Quicklooks. Just add [`/Products('Quicklook')/$value` to the UUID link](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('571a37d5-0573-4176-9cd9-b3dfff6b3454')/Products('Quicklook')/$value).